# Undefined reference to vtable, Qt in Linux

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, ubuntu, qglwidget

I was trying to compile a Qt and OpenGL program under Code::Blocks in Ubuntu 10.04. I get the 'undefined reference to 'vtable for GLWidget'

```
#ifndef _GLWIDGET_H
#define _GLWIDGET_H

#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>
#include "stdlib.h"

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget {

    Q_OBJECT // must include this if you use Qt signals/slots

public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GLWidget();
protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
};

#endif  /* _GLWIDGET_H */
```

I borrowed the code from this guy to see if it works, because mine wasn't working because of the same reason. [Code](http://programanddesign.com/cpp/qt-opengl-code-example/)

And here is the GLWidget.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui/QMouseEvent>
#include "glwidget.h"

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent) {
    setMouseTracking(true);
}

GLWidget::~GLWidget()
{
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
   ...
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {
   ...
}

void GLWidget::paintGL() {
    ...
}

void GLWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) {
    ...
    }
}
```

I removed the code from the GL part to keep it shorter. Should you need it, I can always post it up.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>
#include "glwidget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    GLWidget window;
    window.resize(800,600);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your project.pro file add

```
QT += opengl
```

So it knows that it has to link to GL libraries.

Comment: Thanks. It works now if I compile with QTCreator since I can directly edit the .pro file. But Code::Blocks somehow automatically creates the .pro file. Any ideas how I can manipulate it?

Comment: There might be an option inside C::B to import pro file, anyhow I suggest Qt Creator for Qt development.

Comment: Thanks, I will be definitely using Qt Creator.

Answer (score 3):

Clean your project and run qmake on it.

Comment: You don't know how bitter-sweet this answer is after an hour of getting a vague error message. But thanks.

Comment: and for the record, once in a blue moon you end up having to do it twice...which is even an worse experience because you think something is really wrong with your code when there is NOTHING wrong with it at all...

Answer (score 1):

'undefined reference to 'vtable for GLWidget' most probably means that the definition of the first non inline virtual function of GLWidget isn't linked in the executable.

In the present case, my guess it is that it should be provided by the file generated by moc (but as I don't program for QT, I may be mistaken here).

Answer (score 1):

This happens sometimes when adding Q_OBJECT to a header file and can mean a missing moc_ file.

I have found from personal experience doing the following has resolved the issue:

1. $ qmake *filename*.pro
2. $ make

Comment: Right click on your project root. Click "Run qmake". Fixed it for me. Strange this bug is still around? Is there a bug report?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem after adding `Q_OBJECT` to one of the header files in my project.

I was only getting this error message from *within* QT Creator, and not when I built my project from the Linux command line.

For me, the solution was to delete the `YourProjectName-build-desktop` folder which resides on the same level as your project directory.  Then when I built the project from within QT Creator, it magically worked.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me as well. I tried using "Clean All" from within Qt Creator, but that did nothing. I had to manually delete the folder.